# jquery sortable items question

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Given the following structure, can the div which contains the sortable list be sorted? I ask because with the latest jquery 1.3 version it won't allow sorting of the divs. Is there any limitation with jQuery where it can't sort parent elements which contain an already sortable list, or is it because the parent is a div and not an LI element? Any ideas anyone?

```
<div class="row">
<ul class="sortable">
<li>test1</li>
<li>test2</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="row">
<ul class="sortable">
<li>test1</li>
<li>test2</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="row">
<ul class="sortable">
<li>test1</li>
<li>test2</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: please clarify all your version numbers... I think youve got a typo. the latest jq is 1.3.x, UI, is 1.7... is your version # for a different sortabel plugin or the one from UI and which version of UI and JQ.

Comment: thanks for noticing that. corrected. I use the sortable plugin that downloaded with the UI.

Comment: What code are you using to try to sort them? `$('div.row').sortable()` ?

Comment: yes i have done nested sortable with 1.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess there is a misunderstanding

This command

```
$('div.row').sortable()
```

will actually make the `ul`s in your divs sortable. Which doesn't make sense as there is only one `ul` in every div and sorting a single element doesn't make sense. (Demo page: http://jsbin.com/ayiwu)

---

If you want to sort the `div`s (not the `ul`s or `li`s) you could use this line

```
$("div.row").wrapAll("<div></div>").eq(0).parent().sortable();
```

Now the `div`'s themselves are sortable (Demo page: http://jsbin.com/upixa

---

If you want the `div`s and the **`li`**s (not the `ul`s which doesn't make sense when there is only one `ul` per `div`) to be sortable at the same time

```
$("div.row").wrapAll("<div></div>").eq(0).parent().sortable();
$("div.row").sortable({ items: "li" });
```

Demo page: http://jsbin.com/ujatu

If you want something else please post a comment

P.S.: Sorry for the horrible CSS on the demo pages. Just for clarity that you can see which element you are clicking on